# Calculating Gaussian Curvature in 4D

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature, gauss-bonnet

I am kind of confused by the vast number of formulas for computing the Gaussian Curvature. Having a metric tensor / an expression for the line element in 4D (e.g. $t,x,y,z$ or in spherical coordinates $t,r,\theta,\phi$), what is the most general and neat way to calculate the Gaussian Curvature of a metric?

P.S. in order to achieve maximum generality I would consider a metric tensor with off-diagonal terms, so that mixed terms will pop up in the line element expression.

Comment: What is your definition of Gaussian curvature in more than two dimensions?

Comment: @gangio, Gaussian curvature is an intrinsic property of two-dimensional surfaces only. Do you mean perhaps Riemannian curvature tensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be talking about the [sectional curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sectional_curvature) which generalizes the concept of Gaussian curvature to higher dimensions. The sectional curvature $K$  of a 2-dimensional hypersurface is defined as
$$K(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})={\langle R(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})\mathbf{v},\mathbf{u}\rangle\over \langle \mathbf{u},\mathbf{u}\rangle\langle \mathbf{v},\mathbf{v}\rangle-\langle \mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\rangle^2}$$
where $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are linearly independent vectors tangent to the hypersurface and $R$ is the Riemann curvature tensor. In addition, for a pseudo-Riemannian manifold such as in general relativity, the hypersurface must not be a null hypersurface. The sectional curvature reduces to the standard Gaussian curvature in 3 dimensions. The sectional curvatures in each coordinate direction are related to the the Ricci tensor $R_{ij}$ by the formula:
$$R_{ij} v^i v^j = \sum_{\mathbf{e}_i\neq\mathbf{v}} K(\mathbf{e}_i,\mathbf{v})$$
where $\mathbf{v}$ is an arbitrary unit vector at a point and $\mathbf{e}_i$ is a set of $n-1$ ($n$ is the dimension) orthonormal basis vectors that are also orthonormal to $\mathbf{v}$.

Comment: Thank you. Does the Gauss-Bonnet theorem hold in higher dimensions for sectional curvature?

Comment: @gangio As far as I am aware, there is a generalized Gauss-Bonnet theorem that holds for Riemannian manifolds of even dimension, and it does use the concept of sectional curvature.